# .AddIdentityServerAuthentication() causing System.IO.IOException

Tags: .net, sockets, identityserver4

I have an API that is using signalr to connect to user clients. When adding authentication to this API, I keep getting after roughly 2 minutes an exception thrown from System.Net.Sockets.dll when communicating from server to client:

System.IO.IOException
HResult=0x80131620
Message=Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
Source=System.Net.Sockets
StackTrace:
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Inner Exception 1:
SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Without .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(), this error does not occur. I have seen some people say changing their tls settings fixed a similar issue but this hasn't worked for me.

Here is my relevant startup code:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://myidentityserver.com/";
                //This custom token retriever is so that the access token can be read from a query string for web sockets. With or 
                without this code the issue exists so I don't think its relevant
                options.TokenRetriever = CustomTokenRetriever.FromHeaderAndQueryString;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                options.ApiName = "MyApi";
            });
```

I'm using groups to communicate server to client, and the server to client message is triggered by an http request which kicks off a task. Again, all of this was working until I added the IS auth. I understand it probably isn't an issue with IS access token library, but was hoping someone may know if there are incompatibilities here.

Thanks guys and gals!

Comment: this may sound silly, but it looks like a network issue. check your internet or check if the site you are trying to connect to is up.